# Select multiple columns without join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say you have a simple query such as for example:

```
SELECT p.name, p.age, c.course, c.lecture
FROM person p, college c;
```

Can something like this be achieved in LINQ? the reason I am trying to list a whatever is in those columns and iterate over them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It is called cross join:

```
var result = (from p in person
              from c in college
              select new { p.Name, p.Age, c.Course, c.Lecture });
```

In method syntax:

```
var result = person.SelectMany(p => 
                       college.Select(c => new { p.Name, p.Age, c.Course, c.Lecture });
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Gilad Green's answer, you could also perform the same operation using lambda:

```
var testLinq2 = person.SelectMany(c => college, (p, c) => 
new { p.Name, p.Age, c.Course, c.Lecture });
```

Comment: Nice use of the other overload of `SelectMany`